# Apply a function to each group

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
A<- c(10,20,10,31,51,1,60,1,02,0,12,0,20,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1)
B<- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
C<- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
SUB <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(SUB,B,A,C))
```

I wrote a function calculating the cor among A/B, B/C, C/A.

```
Z <- function(a,b,c) {
  cor1 = cor(a,b)
  cor2 = cor(b,c)
  cor3 = cor(c,a)
  
  x = c(cor1,cor2,cor3)
  
  return(x)
}
```

if I type

```
Z(dat$A, dat$B,dat$C)
```

I get the vector of results:

```
> [1] 0.11294312 0.91417410 0.06457059
```

I need to condition my function to the SUB variable and get a matrix whose rows are  the cor among A/B, B/C, C/A for each SUB.

For instance:

```
        A/B       B/C        C/A
SUB1 0.11294312 0.91417410 0.06457059
SUB2 0.10335312 0.96744677 0.16356059
```

Thank you,
Best regards

Comment: FYI, it's generally bad practice to name variables or functions after base R functions/primitives; `try` is commonly used by other packages/functions in a form of defensive programming. While R is generally okay with determining *which* to use in each context, troubleshooting problems that are based on this will be significantly frustrating.

Comment: Please be careful with your sample data; `C` is length 22, all others are length 23. R is recycling a `1` into the 23rd position, not sure if that's a problem for you (though it will almost certainly change the correlations).

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected it.

Comment: @r2evans I completely disagree with the claim that this is bad practice. On the contrary: name collisions in real-world code are unavoidable, and jumping through hoops to avid them leads to convoluted, verbose names that ultimately make the code *harder to read*. That said, `try` in particular is rarely an appropriate name. Programmers should instead embrace namespaces, which are the tried-and-true way of dealing with this issue. R unfortunately doesn’t encourage this, but the ‘box’ package makes qualifying names effortless.

Comment: I don't disagree with the advice of embracing namespaces, but ... how many times have you helped somebody who was inadvertently using the incorrect function/object? R is not always the most forthright with useful error messages in this regard, at least not for the inexperienced R user. As a more experienced developer, I'm comfortable with naming my variables wantonly (including same as primitives/functions), but newer R users will typically not recognize the signs. Regardless, it's subjective. (And yes, "naming conventions" is one of the two hardest things in CS :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### base R

You can split with `by` and then recombine.

```r
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$SUB, function(x) Z(x$A, x$B, x$C)))
#         [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
# 1 -0.1534126 1.0000000 -0.15341258
# 2  0.1081781 0.8215838  0.04608456
```

The row names `1` and `2` are the `SUB` values themselves; if `SUB` is more "interesting" than counting numbers, it will be more apparent. Column names can be applied trivially.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(SUB) %>%
  summarize(as.data.frame(matrix(Z(A, B, C), nr = 1)))
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#     SUB     V1    V2      V3
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1 -0.153 1.00  -0.153 
# 2     2  0.108 0.822  0.0461
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `split` in combination with `sapply`

```
sapply( split(dat,dat$SUB), function(x) Z(x["A"],x["B"],x["C"]) )
              1          2
[1,] -0.1534126 0.10817808
[2,]  1.0000000 0.82158384
[3,] -0.1534126 0.04608456
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's no need for your function if you use the `upper.tri` of the `cor`relation matrix. Recently you can do this very easily by piping:

```
sapply(unique(dat$SUB), \(i) cor(dat[dat$SUB == i, -1]) |> {\(x) x[upper.tri(x)]}())
#             [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] -0.1534126 0.10817808
# [2,]  1.0000000 0.82158384
# [3,] -0.1534126 0.04608456

R.version.string
# [1] "R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(SUB = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), B = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), A = c(10, 20, 10, 
31, 51, 1, 60, 1, 2, 0, 12, 0, 20, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1), C = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lengthy answer, but it should be pretty flexible.

```r
library(tidyverse)

cor.by.group.combos <- function(.data, groups, vars){
  by <-  gsub(x = rlang::quo_get_expr(enquo(groups)), pattern = "\\((.*)?\\)", replacement = "\\1")[-1]
  
  piv <- gsub(x = rlang::quo_get_expr(enquo(vars)), pattern = "\\((.*)?\\)", replacement = "\\1")[-1]
  
  .data %>%
    group_by(!!!groups) %>%
    group_split() %>%
    map(.,
      ~pivot_longer(., cols = all_of(piv), names_to = "name", values_to = "val") %>%
        nest(data = val) %>%
        full_join(.,.,by = by) %>%
        filter(name.x != name.y) %>%
        mutate(test = paste(name.x, "vs",name.y, sep = "."),
               grp = paste0(by,!!!groups),
               cor = map2_dbl(data.x,data.y, ~cor(unlist(.x), unlist(.y)))) %>%
        select(test,grp, cor)
    ) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = test, values_from = cor)
}

cor.by.group.combos(dat, vars(SUB), vars(A, B, C))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>   grp   A.vs.B  A.vs.C B.vs.A B.vs.C  C.vs.A C.vs.B
#>   <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 SUB1  -0.153 -0.153  -0.153  1     -0.153   1    
#> 2 SUB2   0.108  0.0461  0.108  0.822  0.0461  0.822
```

In essence, what we are doing is splitting the data by group, and then applying a `cor` test to every combination of the selected variables. The way I set this up will give some duplicate tests (e.g., A.vs.B and B.vs.A). You could fix this by using `combn` instead of `full_join`, but I didn't take the time to work out the details. This function should work if you change the input variables, the grouping variables, ect. You can also apply multiple groups with this method.